# Why does the type of quote change the value of the string? - Python

Tags: python, string, escaping, quotes

```
In[1] : '\"""'
Out[1]: '"""'

In[2] : "\""""
Out[2]: '"'
```

In the following examples (in which I'm using python 3), why does changing the type of quote used to enclose a string change the actual value of the string? I'd expect `"\""""=='\"""'` to be true, but it's false. And why does the second example return only a single double quote? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `"\""""` is two string literals, `"\""` and `""` (or `'"'` and `''`, switching to single quotes for clarity), concatenated together. The double-quoted equivalent of `'\"""'` would be `"\"\"\""`.

```
>>> ("\""
... ""
... )
'"'
>>> "\"\"\""
'"""'
```

Answer (score 1):

In[2] is actually two adjacent strings, similar to `"foo""bar"`.

`"\""""`  contains a first string `"\""`  and a second string `""`.

When evaluating that, Python concatenates them:

```
In[1]: "foo""bar"
Out[1]: 'foobar'
```

In your case, since the 2nd string is empty, you just get the first.

Answer (score 1):

Python does something the same way C does, in terms of string concatenation:

```
'hello' 'world'  ==  'helloworld'
```

That is, if you put two quoted string literals next to each other, with nothing in between, they will be concatenated together. This is the difference between `1` and `2`:

```
In[2] : "\""""  --> "\"" ""
```

So your second input is actually concatenating the string `"` with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The single quote can end only with an other single quote,

hence `'\"` is not a string and python then waits for the other `'` to finish the string

so `'\"""'` is one string and `"\""""` is two strings, `"\""` and `""`

the results are then `"""` because python has to take `\"""` in the string object, whereas the other is just a " with an empty string concatenated

I hope my answer is clear, it is not easy to explain with all these quotation marks